# visual mess caused by end="\r" in print (python)

Tags: python

```
import time
value = input("Please enter time: hr:min:sec ")
if value [:2] == "25":
print ("Invalid time entered.")
else:
    hours = value[0:2]
    mins = value[3:5]
    secs = value[6:8]
    while value == value:
        if int(secs) > 58:
            secs = -1
            mins = (int(mins)+1)
        if int(mins) > 58:
            mins = -1
            hours = (int(hours)+1)
        (secs) = (int(secs)+1)
        print( hours, ":", mins, ":", secs,)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

with the code above, the output I get would be normal and it would print out the timing normally

- 12:12:12
- 12:12:13
- .
- .
- 12:12:59
- 12:13:0

however, if I replace `print( hours, ":", mins, ":", secs,)` with `print('\r', hours, ":", mins, ":", secs, end ='')`,
I get

```
12:12:59  > 12:13:10 > 12:12:20
```

there is an additional '0' in the one's place.
Is there a way to use `'\r' end =''` without any of these issues?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual output. Nothing in your code will print a literal `>`. And where is this "additional '0' in the one's place? Why do you need to use `'\r'` and `end=''`? What do you expect these to do? What is the output you want? Describe it in words or show an example.

Comment: Additionally all the user input code has little to do with what you are asking. Try to write a minimal example that only deals with the problem at hand.  Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 1):

Force all your strings to be the same width:

```py
print(f"\r{hours:>02}:{minutes:>02}:{seconds:>02}", end="")
```

The error occurs at present because the '1' is left over from the previous print.

(An alternative trick occasionally useful for ephemeral output is to pad with the right number of spaces to be as long as the longest possible line, but here you likely want the zero.)

N.B. I personally would use `print(thing, end="\r")`, i.e. reset the cursor after printing.  This paradigm is more common, but remember to print a newline afterwards if you want to revert to ordinary printing.